# How do I properly secure electrical conduit in a garage?

Tags: electrical, conduit, nec, inspection

I failed an electrical inspection (State: NJ) the other day.  The inspector said that because my shed could accommodate a car, the electrical conduit had to be secured better in case a car hit it.

The conduit comes out of the concrete, bends, and is secured to the studs for a short run before turning up and going into the box.  I've been unable to find a good description of how to do what I need to do.

For what it's worth; the conduit was installed by a professional electrician, not me - but I'd just assume fix it myself to get it taken care of quickly.

[image: Electrical Box]

[image: Entrance]

[image: Middle]

Comment: Not a specific solution, but I'd suggest giving the inspector a call and ask what they're wanting to see for protection.  Since they're the one that will need to sign off on the work, they're the best reference for what is required.  Internet guessing may or may not give a solution that the inspector would approve.  It may be as simple as just some additional 2x4 bracing behind the conduit, but that's just a guess.

Comment: Most of that seems to be supported by air clips... Usually they specify clips at a given spacing and sufficient support like 2*4...

Comment: FYI- the pallet and other things stored in front of the panel _must_ be moved. There is a minimum requirement (30x36", I think) for free space in front of the panel to make working on it safe.

Answer (score 1):

I'll agree the request does seem a bit nonsensical, but sometimes an inspector just has to be appeased and "for liability reasons" they won't give any suggestion as to how you might satisfy their requirement. Hopefully the inspector isn't expecting bollard poles!

You might successfully argue that a timber on the floor could act as a curb against the wheels of a vehicle, preventing it from getting too near to the wall and conduits. A 4x4 or 4x6 might suffice. Even a stack of 2x4 nailed together would be reasonable. It could bolt to the floor or, with a little bracketry work might be secured instead to the bottom of the wall to avoid drilling the concrete. Just in case the curb is installed only temporarily..

Another possibility could be a steel plate shroud around the conduits. You wanted to learn to weld, right? :-) A shroud could be bent from, say, 1/4" plate by a fabrication shop or could be assembled from segments of flat bar by welding the joints. A roughly U-shaped shroud bolted to the floor or wall could transfer forces of any impact to the structure, protecting the conduits and conductors.

Answer (score 1):

Option 1

Where it comes out of the floor, frame around it using 2x4s fastened to the floor and wall.   Then, instead of going across the wall at exactly car bumper height, go into the stud bay and up a few feet.  Stay below the level of the bottom of the window … then at that height go across beneath the window to where the panel is.

Option 2

Use RMC instead of PVC and put blocking behind it entirely everywhere a car might come in contact.  If you leave the horizontal run at bumper height and over the studs, fill each stud bay with blocking behind the RMC.

Either of these options should satisfy the inspector that a gentle nudge from someone parking a car will not damage the conduit.